# Why doesn't my capistrano deploy upload my new repo_url master branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I have just created a new repo and pushed up my code to the new branch, in my deploy.rb I have updated the repo_url to the new repo that I created and then I pushed up the new code to my repo.

I then did `cap staging deploy` that runs successfully but when i got to my site it still shows an older version of code not the version from the repo.

Can anyone tell me what that could be?

Comment: did you restart the server? does the upload work without errors?

Comment: can you post the contents of deploy.rb or any other recipes involved in the process ?

Comment: Hey I fixed it and removed the repo folder from my root dir and it went okay